# Pybullet pose in Open3D visualization

Tags: python, open3d, pybullet

I've a problem with the integration of pybullet and open3D. In a nutshell, in the end of a pybullet simulation I have the pose (position and orientation). The I'd like to reopen the same mesh in Open3D and place it back to the pose. In this way I have a pointcloud of my pose for the next processing. I got the pose with getBasePositionAndOrientation. And applied them as transformations in open3D with
`pcd.rotate(pcd.get_rotation_matrix_from_quaternion(ori), center=pos)`
`pcd = pcd.translate(pos)`

the translation seems ok, but the rotation is completely wrong and I don't understand why.
I tried to convert the quaternion in euler directly using pybullet and then use get_rotation_matrix_from_xyz but nothing change. Same if I set center=(0,0,0), the results are still wrong.
Any idea?
[open3d view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqBom.png)
[pybullet view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n92LB.png)

Comment: Can you share reproducible code that contains the transform in Open3D & PyBullet?